# How to deploy selenium test suite in AWS lambda

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, aws-lambda, ui-testing

I have a test suite for UI testing. The same suite I can run on my local machine and it working fine, but I want to deploy the same suite into AWS Lambda.
I tried it but AWS lambda filed to lunch Chrome for testing.

Answer (score 1):

After doing a lot of R&D I am able to launch headless Chrome in **AWS Lambda** 
We need to set the following option while launching **headless chrome** in **AWS Lambda**.

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("headless");
    options.addArguments("window-size=1366,768");
    options.addArguments("--single-process");
    options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
    options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
    options.addArguments("--user-data-dir=/tmp/user-data");
    options.addArguments("--data-path=/tmp/data-path");
    options.addArguments("--homedir=/tmp");
    options.addArguments("--disk-cache-dir=/tmp/cache-dir");
```

Complete Implementation:
https://github.com/pbgarodi/Automation-testing-using-aws-lambda